# How to remove the nix volume on macOS 10.15?

Tags: catalina

I tried out nix, but wasn't happy with it. I tried to uninstall it by removing `~/.nix-*` and it worked fine, but removing `/nix` results in the following error.

```
rm: /nix/.Trashes: Operation not permitted
rm: /nix: Resource busy
```

How do I remove/unlink this directory?
`lsof +d /nix` gives no output.

Comment: I don’t know of any `/nix` volume on macOS.  Also, I’ve only seen the `.Trashes` folder on USB and NAS volumes.  Are you certain you’re seeing this on your macOS volume?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo rm -rf ~/nix` and `sudo rm -rf /nix/` ?

Comment: Trashes is generally a hidden folder on at least every volume on a Mac

Comment: In terminal, try these two commands: `sudo chflags noschg /nix` and `sudo chflags nouchg /nix` (you will be asked to enter your login password at the first use of `sudo`). Once you have entered those two commands, try deleting it again. If it doesn't work, try the same commands on any folders within the `/nix/` folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to open Disk Utility and remove the "Nix Store" volume from there

Comment: If removing the Nix Store volume via Disk Utility fails, try again after restarting your computer